# MP3 file uploaded to S3 doesn't play

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, wechat

I have a WeChat mini program that uploads MP3 files created from WeChat's own [RecorderManager](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/api/getRecorderManager.html).

```
wx.uploadFile({
  url: `${config.serverBaseUrl}/audio_reviews`,
  filePath: this.data.audioFile,  
  name: 'file',
  formData: {
    user_id: currentUser.id,
    movie_id: movieId,
  },
  header: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  success(res) {
    // success handler
  }
})
```

My Node.js server uses koa-body to allow multipart/form-data uploads.

```
const body = require('koa-body');
app.use(body({
  multipart: true,
  formidable: {
    keepExtensions: true,
  }
}));
```

And the upload audio file endpoint uploads the file to AWS S3.

```
createAudio: async (ctx, next) => {
  const pg = new Client(config.pgConfig);
  await pg.connect();
  const body = ctx.request.body;
  const file = ctx.request.files.file;

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'myS3Bucket',
    Body: fs.createReadStream(file.path),
    Key: file.path,
    ContentType: 'audio/mpeg',
  };

  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    };

    if (data) {
      // success handler
    };
  });
}
```

The file was uploaded to S3, but when I downloaded the file, there was no sound. I can confirm that the recording played properly before it was uploaded to the server. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, using request module to download a file and piping the fs.createWriteStream(file) to a specified path. I set the "finish" listener to wait for the file to completely download, and then handled the upload in the callback.

```
files
.filter(file => file.length)
  .map(file => {
    let fileName = `${path.resolve()}/files/mp3/${getFilename(file)}`
    let filePath = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)

    let options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: file
    };
  if(!fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
      request(options).pipe(filePath) 
      filePath.on('finish', () => uploadFile(bucket, fileName))
     }
});
```

Like your issue, my file was fine after written to disk, but after trying to download the link from s3, it wouldn't play. Turns out it was being written to s3 prior to complete download (hence in s3 each file had a 0B size).